# Ember-cli moving files to an external folder

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

So I have an ember CLI app that's in something like 'c:/foo/bar/ember' 
and want to have the final generated files copy to 'c:/foo/emberApp'.

When I do the broccoli build i get all the built files into c:/foo/bar/ember/dist. I'd like to pick some of these files and move them to c:/foo/emberApp. What's the best way to go about this? I've seen people use grunt but this would mean I lose the broccoli speed increase. My brocfile is just the basic ember-cli one, no modifications. I'll include below in case it's of any help.

Brocfile.js

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');


var app = new EmberApp({
    storeConfigInMeta: false
});


module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `output-path` argument to build like so `ember build --output-path=/your/desired/path`.

More info can be found in [this](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-ember-cli) section of the docs and in the [source](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/lib/commands/build.js).