# Change public assets folder path in Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to deploy an app to Parse.com Hosting which uses the `public` folder to serve a website, and therefore I would like to make my `dist` folder the public folder, and rename the `public` folder.

However, Ember-CLI requires putting assets in that folder, and I cannot figure out how or if this can be changed?

Comment: Why do you care what the name of the folder is? Copy what you need to the public folder on your hosting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember-cli moving files to an external folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363120/ember-cli-moving-files-to-an-external-folder)

Comment: I guess I can make a Git submodule or some symlinks or something but I'd like to have just one folder of files and not have to do manual copying everytime I want to deploy the code.  This is also not a duplicate so please remove that status.  They are two different ideas.  The "duplicate" answer addresses where ember-cli puts files on build.  My question is about specifying a different folder for where ember-cli looks for public assets.

Comment: When you deploy you don't need to copy your entire ember app, all you need is the contents of dist

Comment: Which is exactly why I want want to change the name of my dist/ folder to public/, as I said in the question.  I would like to version control my whole Ember app as well as the required Parse.com folder structure (config/,cloud/,public/) and am simply wondering if there is a way to change what folder is used for public assets in ember-cli.  Appreciate your help thus far though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is essentially "changing the public assets folder is within Ember-CLI's internals and you don't really need to change it anyway, so just set something else up."

Per @Basement Keyboard Hero's suggestion I just made another folder `ember-app/parse/public`, which I made my output path:

`ember build --environment production --output-path parse/public`

Answer (score -1):

You only need to copy the contents of `dist/` folder to your hosting, so you won't have to worry about output paths too much. Just upload the local `dist` directory contents under the remote `public` directory, and that should do it.

The whole ember-cli structure is only used in development. The build process takes care of compiling all your dependencies in the `vendor.js` file, plus the custom `yourappname.js` file. Also true for stylesheets. So `dist` is your compiled, production-ready app, containing everything you need.

Anything keeping you from trying/using this method?